# Count specific range of output as 1 single output

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, led, photoresistor

The LDR sensor gives a range of values to show whether a LED is OFF/ON, let's say above LDR range 400, the led is ON. When a LED is ON, after reading the sensor values it shows above LDR range 800, because the LDR sensor measuring in ms, a single LED blink shows six LDR 800+ values. Is there any way to count all the six  LDR 800+ values to increase counter by 1?

Here's my output in serial monitor. 314 to 322 is led OFF state and 816 to 851 is led ON state.

```
LED : 314
LED : 314
LED : 314
LED : 321
LED : 322
LED : 322
LED : 816
LED : 817
LED : 818
LED : 817
LED : 817
LED : 815
LED : 351
LED : 329
LED : 323
LED : 327
LED : 326
LED : 339
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: what do you observe when you are counting flashes of a light? ... write your program to do the same

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct problems here.

The first problem is to convert the analog reading into a binary value.
You measure a value between 314 and 856, and you want to know whether
the LED is ON or OFF. The simplest solution is to compare the reading to
a threshold that is roughly in the middle of the range you measure. You
could say, for example, that the LED of OFF if the reading is below 580,
and is ON otherwise:

```cpp
bool led_is_on = analogRead(ldr_pin) >= 580;
```

If the readings are noisy while they cross the threshold (does not seem
to be the case in the short span of data you show), you may want to use
some noise cancelling techniques. You could, as suggested by Michel
Keijzers, require multiple consecutive “ON” reading before deciding the
LED is actually ON. Or you may research the technique of using
*hysteresis*, which would be my favorite solution, as it is extremely
simple. However, if your readings are always as clean as what you are
showing us (never fluctuating mid-range), you can stick with the simple
threshold solution shown above.

The second problem is called *edge detection*. You want to count the
blinks. For this, you need to count how many times the LED *turns* ON,
which is not the same as how many times the LED *is* ON. You know that
the LED turned ON if you just detected it is ON and, *on the previous
iteration* it was OFF. So you have to remember whether the LED was ON
last time you looked at it. This means you have to store this
information (whether the LED was ON) in a `static` (or, if you prefer,
global) variable. Which leads to the following program:

```cpp
int blink_count;

void loop() {
    static bool led_was_on = false;
    bool led_is_on = analogRead(ldr_pin) >= 580;
    if (!led_was_on && led_is_on) {
        blink_count++;
    }
    led_was_on = led_is_on;
}
```

Note the condition: `!led_was_on && led_is_on` means “The LED was *not*
ON and now it is ON”.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the value 400 is used for exactly, but the code below is for increasing the counter when at least 6 consecutive values above 800 are occurred.

The key is to use a state machine.
I don't have a compiler at hand so forgive possible syntax errors.
First we define a state. In your case, there are only two possibilities, so a boolean (`bool`) is used, normally an `enum` is used.

```
bool _counting = FALSE;
```

We also need a constant (or define) and a counter to see how many ON values are needed before incrementing the counter, which counts downwards to 0 (and can go negative when more ON values occur).

```
const int MIN_FLASH_LENGTH = 6;
int _onBeforeIncrementing = MIN_FLASH_LENGTH;
```

However, we can use the last variable to see if counting is occurring, so we do not have to use the boolean above.

Then we need a counter for the amount of flashes itself:

```
int _amountOfFlashes = 0;
```

Both of these are global variables.

Furthermore, in the loop, we need to check for the LED value.

Thus the entire code will be:

```
const int MIN_FLASH_LENGTH = 6;

int _onBeforeIncrementing = MIN_FLASH_LENGTH;
int _amountOfFlashes = 0;

void loop()
{
    int ledValue = getLedValue(); // Use your code here
    if (ledValue >= 800)
    {
        _onBeforeIncrementing --;
        if (_onBeforeIncrementing == 0)  // Flash of enough length occurred
        {
            _amountOfFlashes++;
        }
    }
    else // Restart counting
    {
        _onBeforeIncrementing = MIN_FLASH_LENGTH;
    }
}
```

The code fragment

```
if (_onBeforeIncrementing == 0)
{
    _amountOfFlashes++;
}
```

can be reduced to:

```
 _amountOfFlashes += (_onBeforeIncrementing == 0) : 1 : 0;
```

Also note if you have more code to add, to use the name LED or LDR into the global variables for clearity.

Comment: For a single blink in LED, I'm getting multiple 800+ values. I want them to count as a single value until it drops below 800. So, the counter will increase by 1 if the values cross 800 until it drops below 800 again. So, I wanted to know if there is any way to make this as a range code where all the values will count as 1.

Comment: I appreciate your help, although I do have multiple LDR and LEDs to count, so I wanted to have something unified.

Comment: In that case use arrays for each led (global variable). This will cost 800 bytes if you make it a single (signed) byte.

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding you want to count the values where your LED is on (800+ values in your case).

For this you can simply create an if condition where in you say if the value is greater than 800 increase counter by 1

```
int count = 0;

if(value>=800):
    count++
```

Here the variable value is the data you are printing on your serial monitor and count is your counter.

Also add the if condition inside the loop function and the declare the variable count = 0 outside the loop function

Comment: For a single blink in LED, I'm getting multiple 800+ values. I want them to count as a single value until it drops below 800. So, the counter will increase by 1  if the values cross 800 until it drops below 800 again.  So, I wanted to know if there is any way to make this as a range code where all the values will count as 1.

Comment: Exactly what I did above if you print count on the serial monitor you will see that count increases each time your value goes above 800. If you want to reset it just add `else: count = 0` and count will reset to zero as soon as your value goes below 800

Comment: look, for a single blink i'm getting multiple 800+ values. if i , use  for ( values >800){ counter++;} my counter increases by 6-7 at a time for a single blink. using this condition because of multiple 800+ values it increases counter by a lot for a single blink. and I don't want that. i want to increase that by 1. i couldn't think about anything that would solve this.  you can refer to my question. i have added serial monitor output.